# How to access closest element in AngularJS (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could I properly access the closest element, as the below jQuery code accomplishes, in Angular without using jQuery?

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  function handler($event) {
    if(!($event.target).closest(element).length) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        $parse(attrs.clickOutside)(scope);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What that code is *really* doing is checking if `$event.target` is a child of `element`.  So you can use `parent` to keep going up the tree and check if any of them are `element`

Comment: Show the relevant html and where `handler` is being used. Being inside a directive one might  assume that event is bound to element or a descendant and therefore condition would always be true

Comment: what are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?  This comes off as an XY question, because you ask how to do something from one framework in context of another framework, but don't actually explain why you need the function.  There is probably a way to accomplish your task without having to resort to this kind of manipulation.  And just so you are aware, using `element` **is** using JQuery if it is available, or JQLite otherwise.  you aren't escaping the JQuery way of thinking here.

Comment: I'm trying to test whether `$event.target` is inside `element`. More specifically, did the user click something inside the element in question or outside. I had working code using jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid using jQuery in my Angular app and instead rely on the jQlite subset which Angular comes with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up simply checking if the element contains `$event.target`. The key here is that you must access `element[0]` and not simply `element`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  function handler($event) {
    if (!element[0].contains($event.target))  {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        $parse(attrs.clickOutside)(scope);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be used to extend the angular.element functionality:

```
angular.element.prototype.closest = function closest( selector )
{
  if( selector && selector.length )
  {
    var startChar = selector.substring( 0, 1 );
    switch( startChar )
    {
      case '.':
          return this.hasClass( selector.substring( 1, selector.length ) ) ? this : ( this.parent().length ? this.parent().closest( selector ) : this.parent() );
        break;

      case '#':
          return selector.substring( 1, selector.length ) == this[0].id ? this : ( this.parent().length ? this.parent().closest( selector ) : this.parent() );
        break;

      default: //tagname
          return ( this[0].tagName && selector.toLowerCase() == this[0].tagName.toLowerCase() ) ? this : ( this.parent().length ? this.parent().closest( selector ) : this.parent() );
        break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return this.parent();
  }
}
```